# Некорректная работа плагина jquery-ui autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

При перезагрузке страницы и начале ввода не работает плагин jquery-ui autocomplete. При продолжении ввода начинает работать, но с первого символа не хочет.
с помощью ajax запроса получаю данные с сервера для автодополнения.

```
`function getData(data, callback) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "myUrl" + encodeURIComponent(data),
                method: "GET",
                dataType: "JSON",
                success: callback
            })
        }`
```

Callback для функции

```
`function autocompleteInput () {
       var dataInput = $("#myInput").val();
       function success(data) {
         var dataArr = [];
         for (var i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++) {
           dataArr.push(data.data[i].name);
               }
                    $("#myInput").autocomplete({
                        source: brokersNameArr,
                        delay: 500,
                        minLength: 1
                    })
                  getData(dataInput, success);
       }`
```

Вот так вызываю функцию

`$("#myInput").keyup($.throttle(200, autocompleteInput));`

Comment: у тебя стоит minLength:1 ?  дай больше кода где что вызывается?

Comment: а больше нет никакого кода. только инпут и дополнение. убирание minLength никак не влияет